# How do I select text after a <p> tag, but before a nested <a> tag?

Tags: html, css-selectors, web-scraping

Say I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<p> May  4 - <a href="http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/2996976345.html">residual income No experience is needed!!!</a> - <font size="-1"> (online)</font> <span class="p"> img</span></p>
```

What I would like to be able to do is just select the text `May 4 -`....i.e. the text before the opening `p` tag, and before the first opening `a` tag right after the opening `p`.

How might I do that? What would the CSS selector for something like that look like?

Please note that I am not writing this HTML. I am scraping a site where this code is taken from. I have no control of the HTML output. I am simply using this type of markup, and trying to extract sensible data from it.

Comment: The `font` tag is deprecated, you should not use it. You could add a `span` around that text and then you can easily style it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS selectors cannot reach bare text nodes.

However, this is trivial with XPath, which you can use if you're using a web scraper like Nokogiri or a testing tool like Selenium:

```
//p/text()[following-sibling::a][1]
```

Comment: So how would I do this? An XPath is fine too....if that works here. I am trying to use an HTML parser to get to specific text I am looking for.

Comment: @marcamillion if you have control of the html output, wrap it in a `<span>`.

Comment: @ghoppe I don't have control of the html output. I am scraping a page and only want to select specific text that falls within specific tags. I am just using the output I am given.

Comment: @marcamillion looks like BoltClock has your back.

Comment: @boltclock This is perfect....where can I read up more about XPath's syntax other than the w3schools site - which I find confusing and doesn't quite help me?

Comment: @marcamillion: Well I'm not all that familiar with XPath myself... all I have are the [W3C XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) and some random Google/SO searches.

Comment: @marcamillion There are a few good cheatsheets around, try http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/ or the XPath part of http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/XSLT_1quickref-v2.pdf